# Student management web app

Tags: document-management, information-management

We sponsor  students and get them to several schools. We want to manage our students' information  and keep them in a database. Add their personal and educational information. Grades for each subjects etc. Is there a web app or software we can use for this? Preferably this has to work on local host

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, one alternative is to use one of the open source CRM systems like [SuiteCRM](https://suitecrm.com/) for this:

- You can set up a Student as an "Account".
- You can add various fields to an Account to record the kind of information you want to keep..
- It also has things like: Notes, Calls, Meetings, etc. These can all be recorded against an Account.
- It is PHP/MySql, Open source, so can be self-hosted.

Comment: how can i add custom fields to the accounts field. Like picture upload and gender etc

Comment: It has a "Studio" module which enables adding more fields. Best to install SuiteCRM and try out, or check the online manual to understand this.